# Is it possible to remove my commits from a repo i don't have permission to?

Tags: git, github

so I just want to remove my commits from a github upstream remote that i don't have permission to push to, is that possible?

Comment: No. You cannot control a repository you do not own, not even if they are your commits. You'd need to ask the repo owner to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you don't have push access to the repo you cannot change it in any way. If you want your commits removed, you have to ask someone with push access to the repo to remove your commits or make a pull-request that removes the commits and hope for someone with push access to accept your pull request.